Is there a connected graph whose spectrum consists of a single eigenvalue?
Suppose $G$ is a graph whose spectrum (i.e. that of its adjacency matrix $A_G$) consist of a single point $\mu$. Can $G$ be connected?
Equivalently:
If $P_G(\lambda)$ is the characteristic polynomial $\det (A_G-\lambda I_n), $ being $n$ the number of vertices, then $P_G(A_G)=X_G^n$ is zero by Hamilton-Cayley, where $X_G:=A_G-\mu I_n$. Does $X_G^n=0$ imply $X_G=0$? (If so, then $G$'s edges are just self-loops, thus $G$ is disconnected.)

The Perron root is simple for each communicating class (irreducible).    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem

The adjacency matrix $A_G$ of a graph $G$ is real symmetric, so $A_G$ is diagonalizable. Hence, $A_G = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ with $\Lambda$ diagonal with entries the eigenvalues of $A_G$. If $A_G$ has one eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\Lambda = \lambda I$, so $Q\Lambda Q^{-1} =  \lambda QI Q^{-1} = \lambda I$. In other words, the only edges of $G$ are loops. The only such graph that is connected has one vertex.
